# VBS output in column format

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to have my .vbs output be put into columns. However, when I try write the code to organize the output into columns I continue to get an error - Invalid Procedure call or argument: 'Space'

I'm looking for some help on this, thanks!!

```
Call FindPCsThatUserLoggedInto

Sub FindPCsThatUserLoggedInto()

strUser = InputBox("Enter First Name")
strLast = InputBox("Enter Last Name")

Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

's = "Name" & Chr(9) & "Account Name"  & Chr(9) &  "Location" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
's = s & "----" & Chr(9) & "------------"  & Chr(9) &  "--------" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
s = RightJustified("Name", 10) & _
  RightJustified("Account Name", 15) & _
  RightJustified("Location", 15) & _
  vbCrLf

objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ADSPath FROM 'LDAP://dc=hc,dc=company,dc=com' WHERE givenName = '" & strUser & "*' AND sn = '" & strLast & "*'"

Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

If objRecordSet.Recordcount > 0 Then

    objRecordSet.MoveFirst

    Do Until objRecordSet.EOF

        Set objUser = GetObject(objRecordSet.Fields("ADSPath").Value)

        's = s & objUser.DisplayName & Chr(9) & objUser.samaccountname  & Chr(9) &  objUser.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName & Chr(10) & Chr(13)

       ' objRecordSet.MoveNext
       s = s & _
  RightJustified(objUser.DisplayName, 10) & _
  RightJustified(objUser.samaccountname, 15) & _
  RightJustified(objUser.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName, 15) & _
  vbCrLf

    Loop

    MsgBox s

Else

    MsgBox "No users matching that criteria exist in the HC domain in AD."

End If

End Sub

Function RightJustified(ColumnValue, ColumnWidth)
RightJustified = Space(ColumnWidth - Len(ColumnValue)) & ColumnValue
End Function
```

This is the code that I added to organize the outputs into columns:

```
s = RightJustified("Name", 10) & _
  RightJustified("Account Name", 15) & _
  RightJustified("Location", 15) & _
  vbCrLf
```

And

```
       s = s & _
  RightJustified(objUser.DisplayName, 10) & _
  RightJustified(objUser.samaccountname, 15) & _
  RightJustified(objUser.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName, 15) & _
  vbCrLf
```

Here is my output:
[image]

Comment: Which call to `RightJustified` is causing the error and what is the value of `ColumnValue` when the error occurs?

Comment: I changed the Column width value from 10 to 20 and it worked - However, the output text is not aligned. Is there a way to fix that? I though RightJustified was supposed to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that this is a runtime error due to your data exceeding the specified size?

```
RightJustified(objUser.DisplayName, 10) & _
RightJustified(objUser.samaccountname, 15) & _
RightJustified(objUser.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName, 15) & _
vbCrLf
```

Perhaps this change would be needed:

```
Function RightJustified(ColumnValue, ColumnWidth)
  If Len(ColumnValue) > ColumnWidth Then
     ColumnValue = Left(ColumnValue,ColumnWidth)
  End If
  RightJustified = Space(ColumnWidth - Len(ColumnValue)) & ColumnValue
End Function
```

Comment: This worked! but the text is not aligned at out - it's all over the place - how can I organize the text? I though Rightjustified was supposed to do that

Comment: you can't rely on `MsgBox` to be aligned, you should display via a window or some type of report.

Comment: Your solution worked so I marked your solution :). I also have the picture of what output i am getting so maybe you can tell me what's going on.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, you're not aligning because the font treats each letter size differently (notice the exaggerated difference on the lowercase letters), you cannot align text in GUI like you can in a console type app.  You need to use a DataGridView or a report control...

Comment: I'm going to try that and see if I can get it to work.